# What is the .vimviews folder? Is it safe to delete it?

Tags: vim, spf13vim

I don't know what creates this folder.

Can I delete it?

Comment: Please provide a little bit more context. (OS, versions, ...)
Assuming there is the "view" information of mkview (normally `~/.vim/view`) and you don't need the saved view information, yes you can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the [faq](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/wiki/faq), `.vimviews` is just a cache of vim options. It's probably safe to clear, although it may mean that whatever plugin was using the cache may need to re-create it, if actively used.